# How to cite a quote in latex and have the number appear as a superscript

Tags: citing

[image: quote]

I am trying to reproduce this style of quote in latex. As far as I understand, it is a citation.

I have tried using the normal \cite{} command in the {quote} and {quotations} environments but they produce the regular [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0tQl.png).

Has anyone seen this style before and know how I could code it?

I am creating a .bib file in TexWorks, then using the \bibliography{} command to call the .bib and the \cite{} in the body of text.

Comment: Package `biblatex` provides a `supercite` option. How are you currently setting up the citations?

Answer (score 1):

The `cite` and `quoting` packages can help you:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{quoting, lipsum}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Defoe1719,
    author  = "Daniel Defoe",
    title   = "Robinson Crusoe",
    year    = "1719"
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[superscript,biblabel]{cite}

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{quoting}[font=itshape, begintext={``}, endtext={''\cite{Defoe1719}}]
I was born in the year 1632, in the city of York, of a good family, though not of that country, my father being a foreigner of Bremen, who settled first at Hull.
\end{quoting}

\lipsum[3]
\bibliography{\jobname} 
\end{document}
```

[image]